# How to flatten an array with 2 nested objects and make it to one

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am [flatMapping](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) an array of elements where I am getting this:

`tableRowsItems = _.flatMap(data.SoftLayerCancellationRequests, 'items');`

It returns this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11705294,
    "billingItemId": 361643044,
    "cancellationRequestId": 17289674,
    "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
    "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
    "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
    "billingItem": {
      "id": 361643044,
      "recurringFee": 0,
      "description": "Storage as a Service",
      "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00",
      "domainName": null,
      "hostName": null,
      "item": {
        "id": 9571,
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE",
        "longDescription": null,
        "units": "N/A",
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 11705292,
    "billingItemId": 361643052,
    "cancellationRequestId": 17289672,
    "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
    "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
    "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
    "billingItem": {
      "id": 361643052,
      "recurringFee": 0,
      "description": "Storage as a Service",
      "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:18:18-06:00",
      "domainName": null,
      "hostName": null,
      "item": {
        "id": 9571,
        "description": "Storage as a Service",
        "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE",
        "longDescription": null,
        "units": "N/A",
      }
    }
  }
]
```

So at the end I need something like this:

```
[
{
  "id": 11705294,
  "billingItemId": 361643044,
  "cancellationRequestId": 17289674,
  "immediateCancellationFlag": true,
  "scheduledCancellationDate": null,
  "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE",
  "recurringFee": 0,
  "description": "Storage as a Service",
  "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00",
  "domainName": null,
  "hostName": null,
  "item": {
  "id": 9571,
    "description": "Storage as a Service",
    "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE",
    "longDescription": null,
    "units": "N/A",
  }
},
]
```

But I need to make billing item part of that same object, how else can I flatten it more?

Comment: If you do that you will have duplicate `id` properties and objects can't have duplicate keys

Comment: @charlietfl it doesnt matter, I can get rid of one of those ids

Comment: @charlietfl I just edited.

Comment: Ok but you edited out the existing `id` property for `billingItem` in original. Should leave that there or solutions like using `assign()` will overwrite the higher level `id`

Comment: @charlietfl it doesn't matter because I am gonna need only one. For now all I need is the 2 objects flatten into one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Destructure the object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)) and create a new object (using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)) discarding any unwanted properties (like id) along the way.

```js
const obj = {"id":11705294,"billingItemId":361643044,"cancellationRequestId":17289674,"immediateCancellationFlag":true,"scheduledCancellationDate":null,"serviceReclaimStatusCode":"COMPLETE","billingItem":{"id":361643044,"recurringFee":0,"description":"Storage as a Service","cancellationDate":"2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00","domainName":null,"hostName":null,"item":{"id":9571,"description":"Storage as a Service","keyName":"STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE","longDescription":null,"units":"N/A"}}};

// Extract `id` from billingItem, and assign all other
// billingItem properties to `restItem` using rest parameters
// Assign all the other (non-billingTime) properties of obj
// to the variable `rest`
const { billingItem: { id, ...restItem }, ...rest } = obj;

// Spread `rest` and `restItem` back out to create
// the new properties of the new object. Note: we haven't
// added that id here - we've plucked it from the object and
// discarded it
const newObj = { ...rest, ...restItem }; 
console.log(newObj);
```

If you've got an array of these objects just use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a new array of new objects.

```js
const arr = [{"id":11705294,"billingItemId":361643044,"cancellationRequestId":17289674,"immediateCancellationFlag":true,"scheduledCancellationDate":null,"serviceReclaimStatusCode":"COMPLETE","billingItem":{"id":361643044,"recurringFee":0,"description":"Storage as a Service","cancellationDate":"2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00","domainName":null,"hostName":null,"item":{"id":9571,"description":"Storage as a Service","keyName":"STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE","longDescription":null,"units":"N/A"}}}];

const newArr = arr.map(obj => {
  const { billingItem: { id, ...restItem }, ...rest } = obj;
  return { ...rest, ...restItem };
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Andy, can you explain your code a bit? I don't get that `restItem` and `rest`

Comment: I added [] to the object in the question. Since this is an array.

Answer (score 1):

With **lodash** this is one line with [*.omit*](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#omit) and [.extend](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#assignIn):

```js
const data = [ { "id": 11705294, "billingItemId": 361643044, "cancellationRequestId": 17289674, "immediateCancellationFlag": true, "scheduledCancellationDate": null, "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE", "billingItem": { "id": 361643044, "recurringFee": 0, "description": "Storage as a Service", "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00", "domainName": null, "hostName": null, "item": { "id": 9571, "description": "Storage as a Service", "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE", "longDescription": null, "units": "N/A", } } }, { "id": 11705292, "billingItemId": 361643052, "cancellationRequestId": 17289672, "immediateCancellationFlag": true, "scheduledCancellationDate": null, "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE", "billingItem": { "id": 361643052, "recurringFee": 0, "description": "Storage as a Service", "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:18:18-06:00", "domainName": null, "hostName": null, "item": { "id": 9571, "description": "Storage as a Service", "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE", "longDescription": null, "units": "N/A", } } } ]

const result = _.flatMap(data, x => _.omit(_.extend(x, {item: x.billingItem.item}), ['billingItem']))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

More readable example would be with lodash `chaining`:

```js
const data = [ { "id": 11705294, "billingItemId": 361643044, "cancellationRequestId": 17289674, "immediateCancellationFlag": true, "scheduledCancellationDate": null, "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE", "billingItem": { "id": 361643044, "recurringFee": 0, "description": "Storage as a Service", "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:20:42-06:00", "domainName": null, "hostName": null, "item": { "id": 9571, "description": "Storage as a Service", "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE", "longDescription": null, "units": "N/A", } } }, { "id": 11705292, "billingItemId": 361643052, "cancellationRequestId": 17289672, "immediateCancellationFlag": true, "scheduledCancellationDate": null, "serviceReclaimStatusCode": "COMPLETE", "billingItem": { "id": 361643052, "recurringFee": 0, "description": "Storage as a Service", "cancellationDate": "2018-11-27T10:18:18-06:00", "domainName": null, "hostName": null, "item": { "id": 9571, "description": "Storage as a Service", "keyName": "STORAGE_AS_A_SERVICE", "longDescription": null, "units": "N/A", } } } ]

const result = _.flatMap(data, x => _(x)
   .extend({item: x.billingItem.item})
   .omit(['billingItem'])
   .value()
);
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This pretty much reads out exactly what is happening which is one of the advantages of `lodash` chaining when it comes to code readability etc.

Comment: With this I am getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined`

Comment: I added [] to the object in the question. Since this is an array

Comment: Check the last update I did. I posted a more bigger json.

Comment: Ok that helps. See the updated answer and thanks for the details.